# Change text for a UIButton

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, text, uibutton

I´m making a quiz game, and I want buttons to show the answer alternatives for the question.. 
I know how to do it if I use label.text but how can I do the same just with a button?

Please help! thanks

Answer (score 2):

[button setTitle:@"New Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

easy to see this from [apples docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Comment: Damn, beat me by 3 seconds :-p

Answer (score 0):

You set the title text of the button:

```
[button setTitle:@"Answer 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
yourButton.titleLabel.text = @"";
```